# Application keeps opening new Sessions in Oracle (Java + Spring)

Tags: java, spring, oracle, session, connection-pooling

The spring application runs multiple parallel threads, executing thousands of queries towards Oracle Database from multiple datasources during a Job's lifecycle.
The issue is observed in a specific datasource while handling exceptions.
We use JDBC Pooling with the following configuration:

```
<bean id="connCachingProps"
    class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertiesFactoryBean">
    <property name="properties">
        <props>
            <prop key="PropertyCheckInterval">30</prop>
            <prop key="MinLimit">0</prop>
            <prop key="MaxLimit">100</prop>
            <prop key="TimeToLiveTimeout ">180</prop>
            <prop key="MaxStatementsLimit">10</prop>
            <prop key="InactivityTimeout">60</prop>
            <prop key="ConnectionWaitTimeout">600</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="appDS" class="oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource" destroy-method="close">
    <property name="URL" value="${appds.url}"/>
    <property name="user" value="${appds.user}"/>
    <property name="password" value="${appds.password}"/>
    <property name="connectionCacheProperties" ref="connCachingProps"/>
    <property name="connectionCacheName" value="appDS" />
    <property name="connectionCachingEnabled" value="true"/>
</bean>

<bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="appDS" />
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">com.company.base.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.cache.provider_class">org.hibernate.cache.NoCacheProvider</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">none</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>
```

It is normal (based on application's logic) some queries to get exceptions (basically for not existing customer info in some tables).
These exceptions are handled by the source code and we are 100% sure that the JDBC Connection is released and also the Sessionfactory.Session is closed.
(We use .OpenSession() and .CloseSession() instead of .GetCurrentSession() and .Flush() because we have several queries running on multiple transactions and rollback would not be that easy otherwise)

While the application is not getting any exception, the pool is maintaining a specific number of opened sessions in Oracle DB which are re-used to open and close JDBC connections for the execution of the queries.

After the application handles an exception, the pool is opening a new session to serve the next JDBC connections and the previous session remains opened and idle in Oracle Server.

That makes the application reaching Oracle's maximum sessions at sometime and therefore cannot get any new JDBC connection and the application freezes...

Does anyone have any idea where to address the issue.

I understand that my description may be "high level" but prior raising this question here I've tried almost everything I've found or know. I'm working on this problem for a long time.
In case you need any further details, please ask me.

- Spring Framework: 4.3.18
- Hibernate: 3.6.10
- Web Server: Tomcat 9
- Java: 1.8
- JDBC Driver: ojdbc8 v12.2.0.1
- Oracle Version: 19c

Comment: Is it happening within 1 min of starting the application, or this connection piling up is happening after a long time?

Comment: It may happen in both cases. From what I've seen so far, it is 100% related on exceptions. Whenever we are getting an exception, although it is correctly handled, the application after that, opens a new session.

Comment: Can you post code to replicate the kind of exceptions?

Comment: I wish it could be that easy. Unfortunately I cannot post code. It is a very complex code. There are several calls between Classes and also the actual sql statements are called from Velocity scripts that are being parsed. I would have to post half of the project. :-(

Comment: Without code, it's going to be **really** hard for anyone to help.  What you are describing are absolute classic symptoms of failing to close resources appropriately.  Unfortunately, if I had a nickel for every time someone said they were 100% certain they were closing resources appropriately when it turned out that in some cases they weren't, well, I could certainly afford to buy a few bags of chips out of the vending machine.

Comment: @JustinCave Fair. I totally understand that. I would have answered exactly the same if I was you.
In any case, it is almost impossible to share code.
As already said, I'd have to post half of the project. It is huge and complex.

Comment: @JustinCave I have checked the exceptions handling hundreds of times with various ways.
(advanced logging, counters, external application etc etc)
That makes me 99.9% sure (100% cannot be said by anyone).
In any case, if you see me description, I'm just asking for suggestions on where to address my troubleshooting.

Comment: @JustinCave I guess there are several developers that have faced such issues (db sessions related) that could share some hints with me.
I may have missed something in all the thing I've done so far to troubleshoot.

Comment: Since you can seem to show that the issue is the result of the exception handlers, I'd start by trying to come up with the simplest piece of code that reproduces the problem.  Get rid of all the complexity that prevents you from posting code here.  Build the simplest piece of code that replicates what you are doing, see if that causes problems.  If not, add in a piece of complexity from the actual application until you replicate the issue.